# How do you model Layover and Travel Duration in a Graph

Tags: java, spring-boot, jgrapht

We are creating a replica of amtrak.com and would like to implement a search algorithm for finding paths between station A and station B.

We currently are unable to effectively filter search options at the graph level. For example, two trips, trip 1 and trip 2, that go from station A->B->C might result in a (valid but inefficient) result in return trip 1 from A->B then transfer to trip 2 for B->C.

Our current model is as follows:

```
class Route {
  int id
  List<Trip> trips
}

class Trip {
  int id
  List<Stop> stops
}

class Stop {
  String station
  Time arrival
  Time departure
  int sequence
}
```

We are currently leveraging JGraphT as follows:

```
Graph<StationEntity, StopTimeEntityEdge> g = new SimpleDirectedGraph<>(StopTimeEntityEdge.class);
for (TripEntity trip : tripRepository.findAll()) {
  List<StopTimeEntity> stops = trip.getStops();
  for (int i = 0; i < stops.size(); i++) {
    g.addVertex(stops.get(i).getStation());
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < stops.size() - 1; i++) {
    g.addEdge(stops.get(i).getStation(), stops.get(i + 1).getStation(), new StopTimeEntityEdge(stops.get(i), stops.get(i + 1)));
  }
}
AllDirectedPaths<StationEntity, StopTimeEntityEdge> searchAlgorithm = new AllDirectedPaths<>(g);
List<GraphPath<StationEntity, StopTimeEntityEdge>> iPaths = searchAlgorithm.getAllPaths(fromStation, toStation, true, 9999);
return iPaths;
```

The full source code can be seen [here](https://github.com/SaffatHasan/se577-train-system/blob/refactor-itinerary/src/main/java/edu/drexel/TrainDemo/trips/services/TripService.java).

This problem is additionally discussed [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=xT8qBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA918&lpg=PA918&dq=model%20layover%20as%20graph%20edge%20weight&source=bl&ots=tmLLBjq-kO&sig=ACfU3U0tGkZ_lwzjZpWppRiT1YatRZz1xg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUru3Yz6boAhXEmnIEHfhNBk4Q6AEwAHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=model%20layover%20as%20graph%20edge%20weight&f=false), but I'm having some difficulty constructing the augmented graph.

Comment: From your descript it is unclear to me what the problem is. (1) is this a conceptual graph problem? (2) is this an implementation/algorithmic problem? I don't understand the problem or what you want to accomplish. Also, your code is not consistent. In the first code snippet you define Route, Trip and Stop classes, in the 2nd snippet you use StationEntity, StopTimeEntityEdge, TripEntity, neither of which are defined. Please revise your question to make it clear. What are the expected input and output?